# Android: Taking snapshot activity include camera and 3D object

Tags: android

I have researched to find solution to take a snapshot of current activity and I found 2 solutions to taking a snapshot, but all of them can't help me get right thing which I want.

My activity use camera, and I show 3D object in that layout (same as AR, but not use marker, just draw 3D object in camera frame).

So when I use found solutions, I just get Parent layout (RelativeLayout which I use to keep both camera and 3D object) with some other objects (some button), that bitmap same as physical design screen of XML file.

I used this solution to get snapshot:

```
private Bitmap takeScreenShot(Activity activity)
 {
     View view = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
     view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
     view.buildDrawingCache();
     Bitmap b1 = view.getDrawingCache();
     Rect frame = new Rect();
     activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(frame);
     int statusBarHeight = frame.top;
     int width = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
     int height = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

     Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(b1, 0, statusBarHeight, width, height  - statusBarHeight);
     view.destroyDrawingCache();
     return b;
 }
```

and this solution:

```
public Bitmap snap() {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(this.view.getWidth(), this.view.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
  }
```

But I got same result.

Please help me to find good solution to resolve this problem.

Thanks.